# Add a Windows node to Openshift OKD v.3.11

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Since Docker can now run on Windows, is there a way to deploy Openshift OKD over a Windows VM?

In the documentation under [System and environment requirements](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install/prerequisites.html#system-requirements) we can read that rhel family OS are needed, but I'm just wondering if there is a side process (alternative) process to perform this operation.

My main concern is that I need to run Windows containers on OKD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that for OKD 3.11 this is not possible and has to do with the networking (OVS) not being available for Windows machines.

That being said, there is a lot of information available for Windows Container in Kubernetes itself, although there are A LOT of things that are not implemented or are not supported at this time: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/

You can expect Windows Containers to become available in OKD 4.5 or later as Tech Preview, but I personally would not hold my breath.